# Can a trained Partial Least Squares (PLS) model be used for lossy compression/encoding?

Tags: regression, dimensionality-reduction, partial-least-squares

Once I have carefully trained a PLS model, I know the optimal number N of components for a regressor model.

Can those components and their coefficients be used to lossy compress the original data that
I used to train my model?

And, after that, can I train a model using N components that would be as good as my initial model, using as training set the (lossy) compressed/encoded version of it?

Also, could test data be lossy encoded in this way, without loss of quality of the predictions
made by my regressor model?

I am asking this because when there is a lot of features, but the optimal number of components
is small, I would like to avoid moving around and storing all the feature values which are not
used by the model.

Bonus points: your answer contains a working example in R, for example using the pls package.

Comment: The question is not clear, are you asking about shrinking the size of your data (variable wise) using PLS model using feature selection or are you asking about dimension reduction with, for example, linear projection?

Comment: I am asking if a trained PLS model allows to do some feature selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable selection method for PLS

https://nirpyresearch.com/variable-selection-method-pls-python/

In essence:

1. Optimise the PLS regression using the full spectrum, for instance using cross-validation or prediction data to quantify its quality.
2. Extract the regression coefficients form the best model. Each regression coefficient uniquely associates each wavelength with the response. A low absolute value of the regression coefficient means that specific wavelength has a low correlation with the quantity of interest.
3. Discard the lowest correlation wavelengths according to some rule. These wavelengths are the ones that typically worsen the quality of the calibration model, therefore by discarding them effectively we expect to improve the metrics associated with our prediction or cross-validation.

Discard one wavelength at a time (the one with the lowest absolute value of the associated regression coefficient) and rebuild the calibration model. By choosing the MSE (means square error) of prediction or cross-validation as metric, the procedure is iterated until the MSE decreases. At some point, removing wavelengths will produce a worse calibration, and that is the stopping criterion for the optimisation algorithm.

```
But this algorithm is iterative, so will be quite slow if there are many features to prune.
Although, a dichotomic strategy would be possible to kick start the process.
```

Comment: Using regression coefficients for variable selection can be risky when dealing with highly correlated variables as in spectral data. But if variable selection is a must, it is usable. Removing variables one by one based on CV performance is, however, usually a recipe for overfitting.

Comment: I would start with removing non-relevant variables using empirical knowledge. For example removing constant part, keeping the fingerprint region, maybe removing region belonging to water peak. I would also try sampling the wavelengths, for instance only keeping odd numbered variables and check if the model performance decreases noticeably.

Comment: I implemented this algorithm; in summary:
training set size: becomes 5.9 times smaller.
Model prediction speed: 5.21 times faster.
Model quality: unchanged.